# Amino acid frequencies histogram with letters

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to get some graphical view of the amino acid composition and frequencies in a peptide library.

I know how to create a basic histogram with R but I often see this kind of [plot in publication](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=1280&bih=894&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=amino+acid+freqencies+plot&oq=amino+acid+freqencies+plot&gs_l=img.3...2229.2229.0.3593.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0.1SpUwok_8Dg#imgrc=WU4mETjkqF_u5M)

Can I achieve something similar with R?

Comment: That link shows a lot of different plot types.  Plus your question is a little vague, why don't you show how you have done it already using standard R plotting and then ask how to improve it from there to look more like what you're looking for?  You might want to consider ggplot2

Answer (score 0):

That type of figure is normally produced using [WebLogo](http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/logo.cgi), or similar software.

There's an [R wrapper for WebLogo](https://github.com/omarwagih/RWebLogo). It's a few years old, I don't know how well it works.

There is also [ggseqlogo](https://github.com/omarwagih/ggseqlogo) (more recent, looks pretty good) and in the Bioconductor package, [seqLogo](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/seqLogo.html); I don't know if the latter handles peptides.